# Grid with rows in anchor not visible in GWT (UIBinder)

Tags: java, html, gwt, grid, uibinder

In my GWT application in a composite class I am creating a Grid UI binder.
In each cell of the grid I am adding an anchor UI Binder. When I load this page in the application, I see a table created but the anchor not visible. 
When I insert text in a row,the row with the text is visible but the Anchor is not visible.

The java file with the class

```
public class MetricsTicketsViewImpl extends Composite implements MetricsView {
    private static MetricsTicketsViewUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MetricsTicketsViewUiBinder.class);


    public static final String link1 = "https://google.com";
    public static final String link2 = "https://google.com";
    public static final String link3 = "https://google.com";
    public static final String link4 = "https://google.com";
    public static final String link5 = "https://google.com";
    public static final String link6 = "https://google.com";
    public static final String link7 = "https://google.com";
    public static final String link8 = "https://google.com";
    public static final String link9 = "https://google.com";
    public static final String link10 = "https://google.com";
    public static final String link11 = "https://google.com";
    public static final String link12 = "https://google.com";


    interface MetricsTicketsViewUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MetricsTicketsViewImpl> {
    }

    @UiField GalaxyHubbleHeaderWidget headerWidget;

    @UiField Anchor ticketMetricsGraphsLink;
    @UiField Anchor ticketQueueGraphsLink;

    @UiField Anchor linkk1 ;
    @UiField Anchor linkk2 ;
    @UiField Anchor linkk3 ;
    @UiField Anchor linkk4 ;
    @UiField Anchor linkk5 ;
    @UiField Anchor linkk6 ;
    @UiField Anchor linkk7 ;
    @UiField Anchor linkk8 ;
    @UiField Anchor linkk9 ;
    @UiField Anchor linkk10 ;
    @UiField Anchor linkk11 ;
    @UiField Anchor linkk12 ;


    @UiField Frame ticketMetricsFrame;
    @UiField Frame ticketQueueFrame;

    @UiField DisclosurePanel ttMetricsDisclosurePanel;
    @UiField DisclosurePanel ttQueueDisclosurePanel;

    @UiField Grid ticketTable;

    @UiField ImageAnchor galaxyTicketMetrics;

    private Presenter presenter;


    public MetricsTicketsViewImpl() {

        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        headerWidget.setSelected(GalaxyHubbleHeaderWidget.TICKETS);

        ticketMetricsGraphsLink.setHref(ttMetricsUrl);

        linkk1.setHref(link1);
        linkk2.setHref(link2);
        linkk3.setHref(link3);
        linkk4.setHref(link4);
        linkk5.setHref(link5);
        linkk6.setHref(link6);
        linkk7.setHref(link7);
        linkk8.setHref(link8);
        linkk9.setHref(link9);
        linkk10.setHref(link10);
        linkk11.setHref(link11);
        linkk12.setHref(link12);

        ticketTable = new Grid(13,1);
        ticketTable.setSize("10px","10px");

        ticketTable.setWidget(0, 0, linkk1);
        ticketTable.setWidget(1, 0, linkk2);
        ticketTable.setWidget(2, 0, linkk3);
        ticketTable.setWidget(3, 0, linkk4);
        ticketTable.setWidget(4, 0, linkk5);
        ticketTable.setWidget(5, 0, linkk6);
        ticketTable.setWidget(6, 0, linkk7);
        ticketTable.setWidget(7, 0, linkk8);
        ticketTable.setWidget(8, 0, linkk9);
        ticketTable.setWidget(9, 0, linkk10);
        ticketTable.setWidget(10, 0, linkk11);
        ticketTable.setWidget(11, 0, linkk12);
        ticketTable.setText(12, 0, "linkk2");

        ttMetricsDisclosurePanel.setSize("100%", "100%");
        ttMetricsDisclosurePanel.setAnimationEnabled(true);
        ttQueueDisclosurePanel.setSize("100%", "100%");
        ttQueueDisclosurePanel.setAnimationEnabled(true);

        ticketMetricsFrame.setSize("95%","600px");
        ticketMetricsFrame.setUrl(ttMetricsUrl);
        ticketQueueFrame.setSize("95%","600px");




        ttMetricsDisclosurePanel.setOpen(false);
        ttQueueDisclosurePanel.setOpen(false);
    }







    @Override
    public void clearMsgBox() {
        headerWidget.clearMsgBox(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void setErrorMsg(String msg) {
        headerWidget.setErrorMsg(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void setLoading(boolean visible) {
        headerWidget.setLoading(visible);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPresenter(Presenter presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }


    }       
}
```

The corresponding xml file :

```
<g:Grid ui:field = "ticketTable" styleName="myGrid" cellSpacing='50'>
                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>  
                        <g:Anchor ui:field="linkk1" styleName="myMidLabel">Link 1</g:Anchor>

                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>

                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>  
                        <g:Anchor ui:field="linkk2" styleName="myMidLabel">Link 2</g:Anchor>
                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>
                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>  
                        <g:Anchor ui:field="linkk3" styleName="myMidLabel">Link 3</g:Anchor>
                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>
                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>  
                        <g:Anchor ui:field="linkk4" styleName="myMidLabel">Link 4</g:Anchor>
                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>
                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>  
                        <g:Anchor ui:field="linkk5" styleName="myMidLabel">Link 5</g:Anchor>
                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>
                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>  
                        <g:Anchor ui:field="linkk6" styleName="myMidLabel">Link 5</g:Anchor>
                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>
                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>  
                        <g:Anchor ui:field="linkk7" styleName="myMidLabel">Link 6</g:Anchor>
                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>
                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>  
                        <g:Anchor ui:field="linkk8" styleName="myMidLabel">Link 7</g:Anchor>
                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>
                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>  
                        <g:Anchor ui:field="linkk9" styleName="myMidLabel">Link 8</g:Anchor>
                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>
                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>  
                        <g:Anchor ui:field="linkk10" styleName="myMidLabel">Link 9</g:Anchor>
                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>
                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>  
                        <g:Anchor ui:field="linkk11" styleName="myMidLabel">Link 11</g:Anchor>
                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>
                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>  
                        <g:Anchor ui:field="linkk12" styleName="myMidLabel">Link 2</g:Anchor>
                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>
                <g:row>
                    <g:cell>
                        <div>foo</div>
                    </g:cell>
                </g:row>
            </g:Grid>
```

The corresponding css file

```
  .myGrid {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.myMidLabel {
    font-size: 20pt;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create your `ticketTable` and your links with UiBinder (`createAndBindUi`) and then you create a new `Grid` (re-assigning the `ticketTable` field BTW) and **move** your links to it (`setWidget`), but you never actually use that `Grid` anywhere.

So, basically, you've moved your links to somewhere that's never displayed, so they don't show. QED.